# TTGO LoRa SX1276 ESP32 module receiving garbage data

Tags: esp32, lora

I am playing around with two TTGO LoRa SX1276 ESP32 modules, where one sends and the other receives characters. They are on:

```
#define BAND    868E6
```

They do it successfully. However, for time to time, the receiver receives a packet of characters that includes seemingly garbage or not readable characters. Here are some examples:

```
01.07.2021 11:29:28 Home/Lora/inbound WEMOS Receiver Received:[▒*TJ▒*A▒▒z▒y!▒#▒[                                                                                                             )h▒>0▒▒7D(▒▒&9▒$▒▒"▒"▒%▒▒F▒j▒.▒▒▒▒▒▒n▒▒m▒▒▒
                                       X▒▒^▒▒] with RSSI -120


01.07.2021 13:52:19 Home/Lora/inbound WEMOS Receiver Received:[▒▒&}▒▒[▒&l}▒▒▒▒M1g̓▒      C▒}▒▒^▒▒D<▒Q.=
01.07.2021 13:52:19 uX] with RSSI -119
01.07.2021 14:51:53 Home/Lora/inbound WEMOS Receiver Received:[т▒8▒;;
                                                                     ▒n
                                                                       Y0̈́p>▒&▒▒▒▒W
01.07.2021 14:51:54 ▒,▒F▒▒▒▒▒▒
I▒u▒▒=▒▒4D1*▒يθ▒▒▒;!-v▒▒
```

I guess this could be a parasite or some interference from the environment. Or could it be some LoRa transmission? How can I decode/decrypt this or search its origin?

Comment: Are your wires connected properly? And maybe you could change the preamble to be longer

Comment: Wiring is very basic during operations. Just Vin nothing else. What do you mean by preamble? is it a parameter in the whole setup?

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone, as they say, especially on so common a band as 868. This is most probably data packets, encrypted and/or encoded, from sensors belonging to someone else. Ignore them. You won't be able to decode them.

Change frequencies, and format your packets so that you can recognize what's yours and what's not.